# Python QApplication segmentation fault

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6

I'm trying to run pyt5 on an Ubuntu machine, but even the basic example fails:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world") 

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)     
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)  

        title = QLabel("Hello World from PyQt", self) 
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) #<--crash after this line
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_())
```

when trying to build the QApplication object I get:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

running the same file from outside PyCharm (terminal) yields:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I'm using Python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5?

Comment: through pip (or pycharm project interperter)

Comment: I recommend you uninstall and install the pyqt5 that ubuntu provides in your repo with: `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5`, on the other hand if you are going to use pycharm verify that you are using the correct python since by default pycharma creates a virtualenv.

Comment: should your `if __name__ == "__main__":` really be inside your `HelloWindow` class definition?